# How to get param map as an observable?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to get param map as an observable (i.e. reactive whenever a change in route/ params occurs.

This is the inplementation I have.

But it is not returning any observable value.

Not sure why!

```
id$: Observable<string>

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}


ngOnInit() {
    this.id$ = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((e) => e && e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')),
    );
}
```

and inside the template `{{ id$ | async }}` --> I'm not receiving this.
But when I do a `subscribe(console.log)`, I see the value.

Note that I don't want to do something like this:
Because I want it as an observable, cause changes are reactive.

Following only works when routed initially.

And don't work as soon as any changes occurs.

So I don't want the following implementation and want something as mentioned above.

```
id: string
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
}
```

Comment: You should be able to get it by removing the snapshot property : `this.route.paramMap`

Comment: I'm getting a null value. Not getting any params. I should be able to use them as an observable with async pipe.

Comment: Can someone suggest any idea how to work this out?

Comment: Maybe try removing the filter or use Navigation start!

Answer (score 1):

Comment about listening to `paramMap` is correct, but you need to also change the line `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')` to:

```js
this.id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(params => params.get('id'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `params` and `subscription`

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want a single item use `this.activatedRouteSnapshot.paramMap.get(id)`
- If you want a stream item use `this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(map(paramMap => paramMap.get(id)))`

Note that the first one is `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and the second one is `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: OP already said they didn't want the single fetch version, and the second you are presenting (i.e the answer to their question) is the same answer as what I posted. So what's the difference to my answer? ;)

Comment: The difference is that OP is using the `router` to get the snapshot (which not always worked for me). Furthermore he's doing filtering of routing events: skipping any others that are not `NavigationEnd`. 

I am using the DI module to get the `ActivatedRoute` directly which worked flawlessly across my project

Comment: Yes, exactly the same answer I provided. In the question we can see that `this.route` points to `ActivatedRoute` and I am using `route`, just like you even though you renamed it.